# If URL Element Exists in IMG SRC

Tags: jquery, image, url, src, javascript

How can jQuery code be written that states, "If 'page.php' exists within an img src, then don't run 'example function' on that img. If 'page.php' does Not exist within an img src, then run 'example function' on that image."?

The page will have multiple images, and not all of them will have the 'page.php' in the image src.

Here's the code I've tried so far without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery('img').attr('src').indexOf('page.php') >= 0) {
    example();
}
</script>
```

---

EDIT #1:

Below is my script in its entirety. Basically, I don't want to run this script on images that already have the 'phpThumb.php' in their src URL.

```
var ssWidth = 0;
var ssSrc;
var ssImg;
var ssc;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ssc = jQuery('#content');
    ssImg = ssc.children('img');
    ssSrc = ssImg.attr('src').replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,'');
    genImage();
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if(ssc.width()!=ssWidth){
            genImage();
        }
    });
});
function genImage(){
    ssImg.hide();
    ssWidth = ssc.width();
    ssImg.attr('src','/util/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src='+ssSrc+'&w='+ssc.width());
    ssImg.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented the code so it should be self explanatory:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var contentWidth = $('#content').width();
  //find all images that do not have phpThumb.php in their src attr
  $('#content img:not([src*="phpThumb.php"])')
    //set their SRC attribute based on their current SRC attribute
    .attr('src', function (index, attr) { return '/util/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=' + attr.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host, '') + '&w=' + contentWidth });

  $(window).resize(function () {
    var contentWidth = $('#content').width();
    //find all thumbnails (those containing the string phpThumb.php iin their src attribute)
    var thumbs = $('#content img[src*="phpThumb.php"]')
                  //hide them (why?)
                  .hide()    
                  //update their SRC attribute, use regular expression to find the old width, and replace it with the new onee
                  .css('src', function (index, attr) { return attr.replace(/w=\d*$/, 'w=' + contentWidth); })
                  //show them again (why?)
                  .show()
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Gidon!  Unfortunately, I must have a different issue with my code. The fix isn't as simple as I had thought -- though, since when is it?! :)

Comment: I'll paste my code in its entirety, and modify my question. Maybe it will make more sense that way.

Comment: Gidon - Do you know how to get this code working based on the update to my original question? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Wow, Gidon, that is amazing! It works! There is just one tiny issue. When the window resizes, the image doesn't actually resize. If I refresh the page, the image will resize. Other than that minor thing, you're programming skills are amazing! You know, it's probably fine, since most people won't be resizing their window on devices other than laptops and desktops, which usually have a decent enough internet connection to handle the larger / unresized images. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Now that I'm playing with this code, could we take it 1 step further, and have the script run on other selectors instead of #content, such as: .one, .two, .three, .four, etc.? I tried doing just this by separating the new selectors with commas, but that didn't work. The script would only run if there was just 1 selector (e.g. ".three"). Any thoughts?

Comment: either like this $('.one, .two. .three').find('img[src*="phpThumb.php"]')
or 
$('.one img[src*="phpThumb.php"], .two img[src*="phpThumb.php"], .three img[src*="phpThumb.php"]')